# GraphQL server connection refused in production server

Tags: nginx, graphql, digital-ocean

I have a Angular/GraphQL/MySQL application that I've been developing locally and now I want to put it into production.

I've set up a DigitalOcean droplet and I've registered a GoDaddy domain. I've set up Nginx on the server and created a server block and transferred my client folder to the server and.

When I navigate to the URL I do get the see my client running, but when I want to interact with the GraphQL server I get a:

> POST http://localhost:9000/graphql net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

On my server I do have the express server running, the following error shows if I run my `/server/index.js` again:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9000

I've followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-22-04) but the changes in the `server` block stopped the url from serving the client, so I think that's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue here was that my `graphql.module.ts` http config pointed to my `localhost`. But I've resolved the issue by updating the uri:

```
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink): ApolloClientOptions<unknown> {
  const http = httpLink.create({
    uri: 'http://example.com:9000/graphql',
  });
```

I do believe you need to update the nginx config to include the graphql endpoint:

```
        location /graphql {
                proxy_pass http://example.com:9000/graphql;
        }
```